# Inject html in popup html on load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, inline-scripting

I am trying to inject html snippet in chrome extension (popup.html). The most convenient way seems to me is

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('body').load("login.html");
    });
</script>
```

However, it gives me error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-PjYKV/jd1GXDczCnVop+iWUrSsvAjw3SzEanGI7AbaY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Even though I have in my manifest file:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",`

and also I tried changing it to:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-/oh1xgpyFXn7kJvIaB70H0jKEHLn/1TIiY9wJcLcOLI='",`

Comment: Do it in a separate js file, not inline. See [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](//stackoverflow.com/q/13591983)

Comment: You are right, I got it working, however, I faced an another problem now. As far as I understand, `.load("login.html");` takes more time to load the script and other inline javascript injections take place faster. Do you suggest me to inject all javascript files with load rather than popup.html (`<script src="..">` kind of injections I mean) or is there any other way to inject the html snippets inside popup.html?

Comment: Usually complex projects use a bundler, but if your extension is Chrome-only you can try [HTML Imports](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/).

Comment: `<link rel="import" href="/elements.html">` I tried this too, but it's injecting like iframe. I'd be grateful if you give me an example how you meant it

Comment: The html imports work that way so you'll have to either use a bundler or load everything asynchronously as you suggested.